How is the missing path attribute of a cookie computed or handled in a Single Page Application?
RFC6265 said that

If the server omits the Path attribute, the user agent will use the "directory" of the request-uri's path component as the default value.

Though it talks about the Set-Cookie thing, it also applies to the document.cookie API. To verify this, one can open new tab on Chrome and type "https://github.com/pulls/review-requested". Once the webpage finished loading, open the dev console, type the following code and enter:
document.cookie = "mycookie=114514"


The application tab in dev console shows that the cookie is created with the path "/pulls", which is exactly what is mentioned in RFC6265. But it seems to be a little complicated if SPA is involved (though github is indeed written in react). Let's follow the steps:

Open a new tab to github.com. You'd better delete the cookie above.
In order to change url to "https://github.com/pulls/review-requested" without reloading, click the pull request button on the top-right, and then click the button with text "Review requests".
Type document.cookie = "mycookie=114514" in dev console and check the value in the application tab.

At this time, the cookie is created with the root path "/", even if Chrome's address bar is filled with https://github.com/pulls/review-requested .

That seems to differ from RFC6265. I have tried it on Firefox, which behaves the same as Chrome. I can't figure out the following questions:

How is the missing path attribute of a cookie is computed or handled via the document.cookie API?
Are there any articles that document the way path of cookie is computed?


The "without reloading" part means the new URL must get set via the History API. And apparently the browsers still use the old, previous URL, instead of the new one, to determine the cookie path. They probably shouldn't though.

I can’t check right now, but is that consistent with relative URLs to things like subresources?

But it seems to be a little complicated if SPA is involved - where is this SPA you speak of?

@JaromandaX In this case it is the github page. The React dev tool indicates that github.com is written in react

I didn't ask what framework was used to make github, I asked where is the SPA you speak of?

github is the sample SPA

document.documentURI === "https://github.com/pulls/review-requested" at the view you described, so — according to the spec — what you observed is a violation: "On setting … Otherwise, the user agent must act as it would when receiving a set-cookie-string for the document's URL via a "non-HTTP" API, consisting of the new value encoded as UTF-8."

I have to agree with Jaromanda, here GitHub is not a SPA. Also, if I follow your instructions to the letter I cannot reproduce what you find, in both cases the path is /pulls. Perhaps a better example would be a good idea? Remember that GitHub is a complex website and it might not, against your expectation, do the same thing for all users.

Strictly speaking, it is working within the limits of the specifications. As you noted, the browser will set the path to the request-uri's path component. As the browser did not make the SPA request, the request uri's path component is still '/'.
This has security benefits, for instance, this logic would make it so a XSS attack could not use the History API to change the path and bypass cookie path restrictions. This should be an important precaution for larger websites.
